# Get a users latest youtube videos?

Tags: php, youtube

I'm looking for a way get the following from a users youtube name or url.

1. thumbnail
2. link to video on youtube.com
3. Title of the video

Need to do it with PHP. Is there some youtube api I can use or is something like simple pie my best bet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USER-ID/uploads?max-results=50';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $media = $entry->children('media', true);
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
      $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
      ?>
      <div class="videoitem">
        <div class="videothumb"><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" alt="<?php echo $media->group->title; ?>" /></a></div>
        <div class="videotitle">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php echo $media->group->description; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>      
<?php $i++; if($i==3) { echo '<div class="clear small_v_margin"></div>'; $i=0; } } ?>
```

> ***Code is copied from the post [SimpleXML loop works but breaks half way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248972/simplexml-loop-works-but-breaks-half-way-through)***

It will get a users all youtube videos. Now it is very easy to develop your own.
Know more about YouTube API from https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

Comment: The $feedURL has changed by YouTube. You can now use https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USER-ID&alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published instead. The result from the new location is also different so you will need to change the foreach loop also.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube has got an API available. You can see the reference here: https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/php_client_lib.html

and

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html