# Pull YouTube thumbnails and place in Muse

Tags: html, youtube, muse

How would I be able to pull my latest videos thumbnails and place them in my Muse site?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: @NovaLogic Ah ok, but how would I get the latest video id's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321743/get-a-users-latest-youtube-videos

Comment: Ah cool. Is there a way to integrate php in Muse?